# AT+CUSD=1,"*101#" does not working with two diffence Operator

Tags: at-command, gsmcomm

I'm bulding a program with AT Command to control my Gsm Modem.

My country have 2 operators (VIETTEL and VINAPHONE).

When i push SIM of VIETTEL to GSM Modem (on port **COM21**), I execute command 
**AT+CUSD=1,"*101#",15**

and then, i get result is **+CUSD: 2,"STB: 84981057863. TK goc:0d. De biet cac CTKM khac, bam goi *098#.",1**

But when i push other SIM of other Operator (VINAPHONE) to this Port (still on port **COM21**), I also execute same command. And then, i get result is

OK
ERROR.

Please help me!!!
Sorry because my english is bad.

This is my screen captured: https://anorise.work/SIM.png

Thank you!!!

Comment: If it's the same modem you had been using for both tests, are you sure the second operator, Vinaphone, uses the same short code, `*101# ?

Comment: @mszmurlo yes! im sure two operators uses the same code __*101#__ because i was test on phone and it's ok

Comment: still need answer?  you can try ```AT+CUSD=1,"*101#"``` without "15"

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at ATD command.

And try ATD"*101#"; and ATD"*101#".